# backbone selector and using find

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I am seeing some strange behavior that I'm hoping someone can explain.

From the render method in a backbone view I have been attempting to do the following:

```
this.$(".msg").colorbox();
```

And

```
this.$el.find(".msg").colorbox();
```

However in both cases, although the msg elements are located, when trying to invoke the colorbox method on the returned elements I get an exception that the method is not defined.

However when I use:

```
$(this.el).find(".msg").colorbox();
```

All is well. Is anyone aware of why this might be?

Comment: I'm using Colorbox and Backbone, but I haven't seen that particular problem. Are you sure the method that's not defined is `colorbox()`? Perhaps `colorbox()` is defined but is calling something else that's undefined, or colorbox isn't configured correctly?

Comment: What does `console.log` say about `this.$el.find(".msg")` and `$(this.el).find(".msg")`?

Comment: Tried it out on jsfiddle and all scenarios work so must be something else in my code that's causing the issue! :(. For what it's worth, here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j2NqX/17/

Answer (score 2):

It is a common issue. Surely colorbox is a jQuery plugin. The jQuery plugin is injected until the View's Element is added to the DOM of your Page.

I mean, your code is normal to fail with the natural behavior.

```
$('body').append( view.render().el );
```

But if you do this, it will works:

```
$('body').append( view.el );
view.render();
```

Third party Backbone.js Plugins has a method "named" onRender that is executed after render the View(and assuming that added to the DOM). But if you do not work with additional Backbone.js Plugins just be sure to call the colorbox until your View was added to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Shooting in the dark...

`this.$el` and `$(this.el)` are differente instances even if both make reference to the same DOM element.

Maybe since the moment Backbone did precompile `this.$el = $(this.el)` to the moment you call `this.$el.colorbox()` something has happend so this function is not available and it has never been available in the instance `this.$el`.

I don't know what is `colorbox()` but if this is part of a third part jQuery plugin can be important the order in that your JS code is loaded?

Comment: Interesting speech I have done... but it has not any point since we are talking about the difference between `this.$el.find(".element")` and `$(this.el).find(".element")` and the result should be completely agnostic of what is the difference between `this.$el` and `$(this.el)` at least Backbone is overriding the jQuery `find()` function what is unlikely.